# how to utilize from get_queryset with id parameter foreach particular foreign key items in class based views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

first of all, I am very new to django and thank you for patience,
I want to make web site for showing how the league stands and shows the particular team's footballer
here what I have done so far

**models.py**

```
class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    founded = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(
        League, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="images/", default='images/Wolves.png',  blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    win = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    draw = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loss = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    scored = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    conceded = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    founded = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    games = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    average = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            '-point', '-average'
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.games = self.win + self.draw + self.loss
        self.point = self.win*3 + self.draw
        self.average = self.scored - self.conceded
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

it would be great if I utilize from slug item instead of id
To make easy understand of which league you are in

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path(r'^/league/(?P<id>\d+)/$', LeagueListView.as_view(), name='league'),
```

In order to learn what class based views is I should use them somehow once clicked in th **base.html** 's navbar, it should filter related league's teams

**views.py**

```
class LeagueListView(ListView):
    model = Team
    template_name = "league.html"
    context_object_name = "teams_of_league"

    # def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # HERE I want to get teams of specific league and send to the league.html
```

**base.html**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'league' specific_teams %}">Premier League</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'league' specific_teams %}">La liga</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'league' specific_teams %}">League 1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

[image: league.html file]

**league.html**

*in this file there are table for corresponding league including teams informations*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just Override the get_context method

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(LeagueListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    league = League.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('slug')) 
    context['teams']  = Team.objects.filter(league_id=league.id) 
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you for your time-consuming and help, by the way what if I want to use **slug** fields in my League and Team models ' def league_teams(request, slug):
    league = League.objects.get(slug=slug)
    teams = Team.objects.filter(league_id=league.id)

    context = {
        'teams': teams,
    }
    return render(request, "core/league.html", context)
' with Function Based Views I made it like that **what about in class based views?

Comment: This should be working now